# Red Hat shell: less command is always executing .tcshrc

Tags: shell, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a small issue with less command (this is happening only on Red Hat). Any time I use it is executing the .tcshrc. There is no alias defined for less. I have one machine running Red Hat and one SUSE, in SUSE everything is fine but not in Red Hat.

```
# which less
/usr/bin/less

# less abc
Executing .tcshrc
```

Late edit based on crw comments:
env variable is set as: `LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s`
and running `less -L abc` is working without problem,.

Comment: look into `/usr/bin/less` and check whether it is a binary or script. I guess your `less` is an script.

Comment: nope, is not a shell is a binary file.

Comment: What behaviour do you get from running `/usr/bin/less abc` ?

Comment: @crw the behavior is the same when running /usr/bin/less abc

Comment: Thanks. Secondly, is the `LESSOPEN` env variable defined? -or- What happens when running `less -L abc` ?

Comment: @crw please put your comment as answer, the problem is generated by LESSOPEN environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `LESSOPEN` env variable defined?
`LESSOPEN` contains the path or piped-command and a filename placeholder for utilising an "input preprocessor" (filter) before displaying a file in `less`.

What happens when running `less -L abc` ?
The `-L` and `--no-lessopen` switches disable the input preprocessor.

Comment: the problem was generated by the LESSOPEN, it was set by default to a shell script and that one was lunching a shell.